# Engine Stutters then Dies in Heat + A/C

Tags: nissan, stall

I have a 2009 Nissan Cube with 90,000 miles that has had a hard to reproduce problem for nearly 2 years that the dealership cannot identify.
When driving on warm (70+ degrees f) sunny days, usually (but not always) with my AC on, the car will start having trouble accelerating, then the engine will start to stutter (especially when starting from a stop,) then eventually completely dies out. When the engine loses power, all the lights on the dash turn on and the wheel is hard to turn. If I wait a few minutes and start it up again I can drive for a bit. The car doesn't save any codes when it stalls out.
The car accelerates noticeable slower when I turn the AC on.

Nissan has put two transmissions in under warranty, neither of theme resulted in any improvement. I paid $180 to resolve a cold start code, and just paid them to test the fuel pump, which came back fine after two hours of testing. They didn't test it outside though for some reason, but suggested trying that next time it's acting up

Not really sure what to do from here. I basically can't drive in the heat for more then 40 minutes.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: dirty fuel filter? had it serviced?

Comment: How would a fuel filter only cause a problem when it's hot and on AC @SolarMike?

Comment: @GdD because demanding more power needs a higher fuel flow rate... possible, weird but possible and seen similar issues before. What is your considered opinion?

Comment: I agree, never discount the weird @SolarMike. Fuel filter is cheap and easy to replace, plus may need it after 90k miles, why not try it. Overheating fuel pump? Meh. AC compressor seizing when hot? Maybe, too many possibilities.